# Get row number of json data

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a ajax request which returns data in json format like

```js
{
    "response_code": 1,
    "response_data": {
        "ext": [
            {
                "client_id":"1003",
                "company_name":"Reachmediagg"
            },
            {
                "client_id":"1004",
                "company_name":"RaSpecial"
            }
        ],
        "row_count":2
    },
    "response_error":""
}
```

As you can see the data is inside the ext array inside json object, now I have to get the row number of the data, so I want for example row number of client_id 1004, which is 2. How will I do that in javascript?

Comment: Are you manipulating DOM with this `response` ?

Comment: possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: Could you run the JSON response through a JSON parser/formatter so that it's easier to read here?

Comment: Dude, please show your code.

Comment: response_data is double encoded json (e.g. `JSON.parse(res.response_data)`)

Comment: This question mixes two trivial problems, and this isn't clear from the title. In this way this attracts hits from Google which will all be disappointed. So not a good question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through the ext array in your JSON and find the element that holds the correct client_id. The function described below does just that.

```
function get_row_number(data, client_id) {
    var ext = data.ext;

    // Loop through all the clients and try to find the one with the given client_id
    for (var i = 0; i < ext.length; i++) {
        if (ext[i].client_id == client_id)
            return i;
    }

    // Return -1 if the client_id could not be found
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: you should be looping over ext, not data

Answer (score 0):

*Technically* the data doesn't *have* row numbers.  Only in how you *read* the data can you infer/assign a row number.

Note that `ext` is an array.  You can loop over that array until you find the record you want and keep a counter.  For example:

```
var counter = 0;
for (;counter <= response_data.ext.length; counter++) {
    if (response_data.ext[counter].client_id == 1004) {
        break;
    }
}
// here "counter" is the "row number" where client_id == 1004
```

You can also extract this into a function where the target `client_id` is a parameter (or the condition itself is a parameter, allowing you to look for more than just `client_id`).